# Automatic saving a figure as an image file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, tiff, jpeg, movie, figure

I'm creating 49 figures in Matlab, they are all created automatically one after the other. I want them to also automatically be saved as `.tif` or `.jpg` images with names corresponding to their figure number.
Can I do it? And if so,how?

the code for the creation of the figures is:

```
for num_picture=0:48
  ...
  figure (num_picture+1)
  imshow (screen_im)
end
```

The `...` part is where all the calculations of `screen_im` are.

I want those images in order to create a movie from them, If there is a way where I can create the movie automatically form Matlab, it would be good also, actually it will be better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can save current figure into a file with [PRINT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/print.html) of [SAVEAS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/saveas.html) command generating the filename using loop counter:

```
saveas(sprintf('img%d.tif',num_picture))
```

or

```
 print('-dtiff','-r300',sprintf('img%d.tif',num_picture))
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, have a look at `avifile()`.  However, I've had better luck saving frames individually (compression quality issues if I recall correctly).

To save individual frames, you can use `imwrite()` or `print()` with a `-dpng` or similar option.  From there, use `sprintf()` to generate a filename with your frame number in it, and you've got most of what you need.  You'll need some sort of movie editor program (VideoMach, etc.) to turn those frames into a movie if you don't use Matlab's avifile(), however.