# MATLAB: batch processing of images and, saves these images. How can I do?

Tags: image, matlab, image-manipulation

I'm sorry, I'm a newby. I tried to copy the code find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799311/automatic-saving-a-figure-as-an-image-file-in-matlab/28194377#28194377)
to obtain the same result, but it doesn't work (fault mine). I can not figure out how `saveas` can understand which is the image that has to save. I've read that `saveas` wants a Handle and a filename as input, and in the code that I fund in the link above I don't see these arguments:

```
saveas(sprintf('img%d.tif',num_picture))
```

Here is a short part of my code:

```
% Here a loop that transform aeach image inside the variable(cell array) 'immages'

for z = 1:length(immages) %images is a cell array contained the matrices of 100images
    temp = immages{z};  %temp means temporary, that is the image to process
    for i = 1:I       % begin of cycle that process each pixel of the image(tmp)
        for j = 1:J
            if temp(i,j) == 0
               temp(i,j) = 115;
            else
                temp(i,j) = 140;
            end
        end
    end
    cd(finalDest);  %move into the directory whre I want to save the new image
    figure;
    imshow(temp);
    saveas(sprintf('img%d.tif',z)); % HOW CAN I SAVE THE CURRENT IMAGE(TEMP) INSIDE 'FINALDEST'?
    cd(initialDest); %return to the folder where the original images are contained
end
```

I encounter this error `ERROR USING SAVEAS, line55: Requires handle to Figure or block diagram and filename.`

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, `saveas` needs a figure handle as first parameter, you can get one changing:

```
figure;
```

with

```
h = figure(z); //one figure per image
```

and

```
saveas(h, sprintf('img%d.tif',z));
```

or using `gcf` to get a handle to the current figure:

```
saveas(gcf, sprintf('img%d.tif',z));
```

If you only want to save the information on the `temp` matrix (not the entire figure) you should use [IMWRITE](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html):

```
imwrite(temp,sprintf('img%d.tif',z));
```